# Video - Bootstrap modal not showing fullscreen button

Tags: html, css, video, bootstrap-modal, fullscreen

We are facing this problem.

I'll try to explain the most I can how we are working in this project first of all.

We have a demo page, and another one were we have each element of the demo page separately, called modules. This is because other clients can work more easily while building the "real" page.

Once said this, we have included a video in our demo page. In our modules, the video has a "fullscreen" button, but not in our demo.
We have to say that in our modules, we make a "fake" modal from bootsrap, just to show the clients how it should look the modal once opened. But once we include it into our demo page, this button literally doesn't shows up. We think it can be because the modal from bootstrap it's preventing to show it, but we are not sure. Here we leave some images from our modules and demo.

Modules:
[image: Modules]

Demo:
[image: Demo]

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="ver-video">
        <video controls >
          <source src="video/video-finanzas.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="video/video-finanzas.ogv" type="video/ogv">
          <source src="video/video-finanzas.webm" type="video/webm">
            Tu navegador no soporta el video
        </video>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid wrapper-content">
        <img src="img/icn-step2-incorrecto.png">
        <h4>Text</h4>
        <h5>More text</h5>
        <p>More text</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn-onboarding" target="_top">Link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.modal-onboarding .ver-video {
    background-image: url("../img/Step2_Resposta.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 220px;
    position: relative;
}
.modal-onboarding .ver-video video{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

As I said, we don't know why the button disappears. Maybe because bootstrap modal is preventing to showing it? If it's this, which is the solution? The code from one page to the other is the same one, copy-paste.

Comment: Can you use developer tools to inspect and see if it's not loading?

Comment: @ovokuro the video plays fine, it's just the button from fullscreen that doesn't appear, and console / networking doesn't displays any errors

Comment: But if you inspect over where the button should display, can you see any problems? Like a style being overriden?

Comment: @ovokuro Nothing strange that would prevent a button to display

Comment: Is this happening in all browsers?

Comment: @ovokuro I could test with Safari, Chrome and Firefox. The only one who displayed the fullscreen button in the demo page was safari

Comment: Now that I'm thinking, could a frame prevent that button appear?

Comment: I'm not too sure, but it sounds like browser discrepancies will give you a lead you can work with. Best of luck!

Comment: @ovokuro We found it was caused by `frame`tag. Thanks for trying to help! Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

For what I can see, in Firefox and Chrome, a HTML5 video tag inside a `frame` tag, will make this button disappear. I just tested it with and without `frame`s, and that's what exactly occurred.